# Flushing last column of align* left

Tags: align

In `align*`, I am getting the following:
[image]

with the following MRE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\upd}[2]{\ensuremath{[ \hspace{0.5pt} #1 \leftarrowtail \, #2 \hspace{0.5pt} ]}}
\newcommand{\LTLglobally}{\Box}
\newcommand{\LTLeventually}{\Diamond}
\newcommand{\add}{\texttt{add}}
\newcommand{\sub}{\texttt{sub}}
\newcommand{\eq}{\texttt{eq}}

\title{}
\author{}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{align*}
    \LTLglobally(&~(\upd{x}{\add~x~1} \lor \upd{x}{\sub~x~1})~&\land& \\
    &~(\eq~x~0 \to \LTLeventually (\eq~x~2)~&)&
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

How do I "shift" the last `land` and `)` to right next to the other fields in the `align*`? I still want the `land` and the last `)` to be aligned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved quite readily with `alignat*`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\newcommand{\upd}[2]{\ensuremath{[ \hspace{0.5pt} #1 \leftarrowtail \, #2 \hspace{0.5pt} ]}}
\newcommand{\LTLglobally}{\Box}
\newcommand{\LTLeventually}{\Diamond}
\newcommand{\add}{\texttt{add}}
\newcommand{\sub}{\texttt{sub}}
\newcommand{\eq}{\texttt{eq}}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
  \LTLglobally(
    &~(\upd{x}{\add~x~1} \lor \upd{x}{\sub~x~1})~&&\land \\
    &~(\eq~x~0 \to \LTLeventually (\eq~x~2)~&&)
\end{alignat*}

\begin{align*}
  \LTLglobally(
    ~ ( \upd{x}{\add~x~1} \lor \upd{x}{\sub~x~1}) ~ \land        & \\
      ( \eq~x~0 \to \LTLeventually ( \eq~x~2 ) ~ \phantom{\land} &)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Neither of the options provided above are sufficiently appealing to the eye, but suffice in terms of the request. There are numerous other options as well when it comes to aesthetics.